# how to hide all divs in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, element

I have several divs:

```
<div id="div-1"></div>
<div id="div-2"></div>
<div id="div-3"></div>
<div id="div-4"></div>
```

How can I hide them all with jquery. I used `$('#div').hide();` and did not work.

Comment: `#div` will select the element with ID `div`. jQuery has a good documentation about the selectors you can use, you should have a look at it: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. Why did you think `$('#div')` should work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are using an id in your selector. Simply use:

```
$('div').hide();
```

However that will hide literally all divs. How about you hide only divs that have an id in the form of `div-x`?

```
$('div[id^="div-"]').hide();
```

This will only hide the divs you mentioned without hiding other divs (which might be problematic).

Comment: Perfect answer. Thnx.

Comment: I had no idea that you could use substring selectors in jQuery. My eyes have been opened, and I have seen the light!

Answer (score 6):

for more detail you can read this : [**`Element Selector (“element”)`**](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

this will do : `$('div').hide();`

there is no need of # sign which is for the id selector for jquery , if you want to hide element just write the name of element will do your task thats called as "element selector".

Answer (score 5):

Take out the hash and just do `$('div').hide();` because right now you are hiding all elements with an `id` of `"div"`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you are specifying an *id* in your selector.  Use this instead:

```
$('div').hide();
```

Answer (score 5):

jQuery uses CSS-selectors, so this hides all divs:

```
$('div').hide();
```

However, if you want to hide the divs whose `id` begins with "div", as in your example, do this:

```
$('div[id^="div"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

$('div').hide(); should work

$('#div') looks for id="div" rather than looking for all divs.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#div').hide();`

does not work because you are lookin for something with ID = "div" and you have set your id's to "div-1" etc.

Instead try

```
  $('#div-1').hide();
  $('#div-2').hide();
```

etc

That will hide the specific div's mentioned.

If you really want to hide all the divs on your page then

```
  $('div').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign a class to all the divs you want to hide and then 
do sth like

```
 $('.hider').hide()
```

This would hide all the divs with that class hider. Then you can do whatever you want on some of the divs

Answer (score 0):

`#div` the element who's `id` is `div`, if you want to hide every `div` on the page then the selector that you want is just `div` (use `$('div').hide()`).

I don't think that is what you really want though, you almost certainly do not actually want to hide **every** div on the page. You seem to be trying to hide several specific `div`s in one go. The way to do that is to separate the `id`'s with a comma: `$('#div-1,#div-2,#div-3,#div-4').hide()`.

Alternately a better way to do it is to add a `class` to those `div`s in case you want to change the number of `div`s.

So to hide:

```
<div id="div-1" class="foo"></div>
<div id="div-2" class="foo"></div>
<div id="div-3" class="foo"></div>
<div id="div-4" class="foo"></div>
```

You would use `$('.foo').hide()`.