# Inputosaurus / jQuery load times

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am using [Inputosaurus](http://sproutsocial.github.io/inputosaurus-text/) to add some fancy autocomplete tags to my Client's Management System. It's a beautiful system, in terms of both cosmetics and productivity.

**The problem is the massive load time.**

The HTML page loads up several images (sometimes several hundred) each of which will have its own instance of the same list of autocomplete terms. The resulting JavaScript looks like this in the final HTML file:

```
<script>
$('#tags_0001').inputosaurus({
    width : '100%',
    autoCompleteSource : ["A Midsummer Night's Dream","A Modest Proposal","A Particular Entertainment","A Tale of a Tub","A Yorkshire Tragedy","A.G. Werner","Abbasid","Abbe de la Roque","Abel Berland","Aborigines","Abou Mandour","Aboukir","Abraham Munting","Abraham van Diepenbeeck","Absalom and Achitophel","Abu Mandour","Abukir","Abyssinia Map","Academie Royale des Sciences","Accipies","Accounting","Achaean","Achitecture","Acts of Parliament","Admiral Mendoza portrait","Aegean Sea","Aeneid","Aeneis","Aesop","Aethiopia","Aetiis","Afghanistan"],
    activateFinalResult : true});
$('#tags_0002').inputosaurus({
    width : '100%',
    autoCompleteSource : ["A Midsummer Night's Dream","A Modest Proposal","A Particular Entertainment","A Tale of a Tub","A Yorkshire Tragedy","A.G. Werner","Abbasid","Abbe de la Roque","Abel Berland","Aborigines","Abou Mandour","Aboukir","Abraham Munting","Abraham van Diepenbeeck","Absalom and Achitophel","Abu Mandour","Abukir","Abyssinia Map","Academie Royale des Sciences","Accipies","Accounting","Achaean","Achitecture","Acts of Parliament","Admiral Mendoza portrait","Aegean Sea","Aeneid","Aeneis","Aesop","Aethiopia","Aetiis","Afghanistan"],
    activateFinalResult : true});
$('#tags_0003').inputosaurus({
    width : '100%',
    autoCompleteSource : ["A Midsummer Night's Dream","A Modest Proposal","A Particular Entertainment","A Tale of a Tub","A Yorkshire Tragedy","A.G. Werner","Abbasid","Abbe de la Roque","Abel Berland","Aborigines","Abou Mandour","Aboukir","Abraham Munting","Abraham van Diepenbeeck","Absalom and Achitophel","Abu Mandour","Abukir","Abyssinia Map","Academie Royale des Sciences","Accipies","Accounting","Achaean","Achitecture","Acts of Parliament","Admiral Mendoza portrait","Aegean Sea","Aeneid","Aeneis","Aesop","Aethiopia","Aetiis","Afghanistan"],
    activateFinalResult : true});
</script>
```

Now consider that this example truncates that "autoCompleteSource" list. In actual fact, it goes on through more than 1,000 terms (for each instance) producing HTML character counts in excess of 19-20 million!

It seems that this would be an ideal situation for jQuery to reference an array of these terms (or a variable string), but I'm really not sure that HTML supports this.

I am surprised not to see much about this on the Web. I hope that this is merely my lack of JS lexicon making for poor searches, rather than there simply being no solution.

**I am sure this has been confronted before by others here — what alternate method should I be using in this situation?**

Please let me know if I am omitting any important diagnostic information.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user will input *one* word, sending a few thousands possible words to the client before he actually entered anything is overkill. Instead you should wait for the user to input the first few chars, then send them to the server, query and filter all possible terms and only send those back that are matching, then send that small list back to the client, filter it again based on the other chars the user already entered.

Words to google: AJAX, and`fetch()`.

Comment: Very interesting! So you're suggesting that the keyword terms should be entirely stored server-side?

Comment: I haven't finished this script, but after my initial research there is no doubt that this is the correct tool to use for this. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Accepting and upvoting.

Answer (score -1):

While I believe that Jonas' answer is superior to this one, I wanted to post an alternative solution which I found to be very helpful on another project where a database application was impractical.

The source is this SO question's accepted answer:

[how to hide all divs in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469079/how-to-hide-all-divs-in-jquery)

This instead focuses on the `textarea` element, rather than a div, but the application is the same. It is a `textarea` that we are focusing on.

The new code which would replace the code in my original question is:

```
<script>
$('textarea[id^=\"tags_\"]').inputosaurus({
    width : '100%',
    autoCompleteSource : ["A Midsummer Night's Dream","A Modest Proposal","A Particular Entertainment","A Tale of a Tub","A Yorkshire Tragedy","A.G. Werner","Abbasid","Abbe de la Roque","Abel Berland","Aborigines","Abou Mandour","Aboukir","Abraham Munting","Abraham van Diepenbeeck","Absalom and Achitophel","Abu Mandour","Abukir","Abyssinia Map","Academie Royale des Sciences","Accipies","Accounting","Achaean","Achitecture","Acts of Parliament","Admiral Mendoza portrait","Aegean Sea","Aeneid","Aeneis","Aesop","Aethiopia","Aetiis","Afghanistan"],
    activateFinalResult : true});
</script>
```

That's it. Just one line. Tested and working.